# sensor TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR is not working when screen is off

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, android-wake-lock, sensormanager

in my app i use the TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR. I want to detect steps when screen is off. But the sensor TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR does not work when the screen is off. So I use PowerManager/WakeLock to make the CPU not hibernate. But it STILL not work.

Answer (score 0):

You did't show how is your code show, but I have small code worked on my devices so I will share for you. These case worked perfect with my phone: oppo a55 a12, redmi note 7 a11, poco x3 pro a13:

> Worked when app is in background,
>
> worked when app is in foreground then screen off
>
> Worked when app is in background then screen off
> If you want work when app is killed. Let's use WorkManager, or create Notification to make your app always active

at Manifest:

> android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
>
> android.permission.BODY_SENSORS
>
> android.permission.BODY_SENSORS_BACKGROUND

Ask permission first

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
                    ), 200
                )
            }
```

Then use my class for listen code from sensor service

```
  inner class TestStep(private val context: Context) : SensorEventListener {
    private var test = 0
    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {
        println("sensor: ${sensor}, accuracy: ${accuracy}")
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
            test++
            println("test: $test")
            resultText.text = "$test step(s)"
        }
    }

    fun registerSensor() {
        val sensorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        val stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)
        sensorManager.registerListener(
            this,
            stepDetectorSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
        )
    }

    fun unregisterSensor() {
        val sensorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }
}
```

How to use code above:

> val testStep = TestStep(this)
> testStep.registerSensor()

Finally, shake you phone multiple time and see log . Hope this help.